# How do I transfer video files from an iMac to an external hard drive?

Tags: mac, video, external-hard-drive

Trying to transfer video files from my iMacs HD to an external hard drive but I can't figure it out...tried to import it straight to the external HD but couldn't do it.

Comment: How did you import the video to your mac?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I would say that basic drag & drop in Finder should work.

A possible limitation is when your external HD is FAT32 and your video files are bigger than 4Gb. In that case, you have to format your external disk in HFS+.

Comment: I agree, drag/drop should work - good point about the format of the external HD!